# My website shows different content in Chrome and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I created a website that a has image slider in the front page.
you can see it here, http://www.ikuben.no/.

In Chrome, it works fine[image]

In IE, I get this[image]

This is the CSS i use,

```
.flex-caption {
    width:50%; 
    padding:0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    margin: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    left:49%; 
    top:20%; 
    background:none; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    line-height:20px; 
    font-family:Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:normal;
}
.flex-caption span {
    font-size:30px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-family:'helvetica_neuebold', Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

I did test the website in 6 different browser's, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari for Windows, SeaMonkey and IE. I only get this result in IE.

Any ideas??
Rui Martins

Comment: Welcome to the hell of browser compatibility.

Comment: Hi. Chrome 24.01312.56, IE 9.0.8112.16421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just noticed you add:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000,endColorstr=#4C000000)
```

on the .flex-caption css. Mind if you remove it to see if its the problem? Ty

Comment: It was. The CSS is not mine, so I didn't even noticed that. Tks.